Customs for personal goods when traveling from EU to UK as a tourist?
I want to travel as a tourist from EU to UK and taking my camera, laptop and smartphone with me. I would exceed the allowance of only 390 Pounds:

You will need to pay tax on all other goods if you go over this
allowance. For example, if you are bringing in a £500 laptop and a
£100 watch you will need to pay tax on the watch and the laptop.

There's similar question of a UK citizen. There's also an answer which says, that the allowance would not apply to me as a tourist:

EU (or third-country) resident, device bought outside the UK: you're
presumably on a short visit, if you will take the device back with you
when leaving the country, you don't need to pay tax or duties (and
usually don't need any paperwork). ...

And another answer states similar.
The point is, that these answers contradicts - in my understanding - the statement of the gov.uk site. On that site I can't find any exceptions for short visit tourists.
So is there any evidence on the gov.uk site, that there are exceptions for short visit tourists?

Edited my questions.

the issue is not being a tourist. The issue is will the goods stay in the UK, or leave with you? A tourist bringing a thousand pounds worth of gifts to the people being visited would pay duty. The other questions are clear about that and so, imo, is the government page. You don't see exceptions for tourists because that's not relevant. That doesn't mean you need to pay duty.

Personal goods that you bring for personal use while travelling and that you will take with you when you are leaving are not subject to taxes or duties. That certainly includes your laptop, cell phone, and camera unless you are planning to sell or gift them in the UK.
Taxes and duties are only due on goods that are purchased in one country and imported into another for final use.
If you are travelling with some unusual or very expensive stuff you can consider getting a Carnet. That's a document that captures entry and exit of the goods from a country.
